# How to get the data from a quickbooks report with Selenium using python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, quickbooks-online

I have created a py script to automate the login and go to reports section to pull a custom report. Everything until there works properly.

Where I got stock is to get the "table" with the data since I do not find in the HTML response anything that seems to be a table.

How can I get the information from the report and read it into a Pandas dataframe?

Tried to look for a Table using find, Tried to click with selenium the "Export to Excel" button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.